# Voila is rendering plots, ipywidgets and markdown on one system but only markdown in another system

Tags: plotly, ipywidgets, voila

I am using voila Jupyter lab extension. Voila renders all plots, ipywidgets and markdown on one system but not in another system. All my package versions, browsers are up to date

[Plots not rendering on one system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgvHd.png)

[Plots rendering on another system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXb28.png)

I updated all the package versions, ipywidgets voila versions and browser versions for both the systems

The only difference between two systems is the plotly build and channel.

[Works for this system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d7QD.png)

[Does not work for this system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb9Q7.png)

Also it works for matplotlib on both systems

Comment: I tried again with matplotlib. it working ok. but not with plotly.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [su], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again). They too will want to see what troubleshooting efforts you have put in.

Comment: You already kind of answered your question. Two different systems will have two different installations and packages. One system isn't set up right in the way the other is. Not sure then why you are asking here? Both are using JupyterLab it seems from the screenshots. By the way, you should state such things and not leave it for those trying to help you to have to study images to determine things. Your post is very incomplete if you read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and use it as a guide. You especially want to read ..

Comment: <continued> the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' where it emphasizes not posting screenshots. In your case, it is probably a bit helpful to at least include them as it does involve behavior that is hard to describe completely. However, the question should stand alone without the screenshots. Back to your question... If you go [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?urlpath=%2Flab%2Ftree%2Fnotebooks%2FDonut%20plot%20on%20a%20widget%20tab.ipynb) and after the session starts, drag-and-drop in your notebook and data, does it work? If so, you can use ...

Comment: <continued> as a way to troubleshot the computer that isn't working. Or just use that for development on the system with the installation that isn't working. Getting the correct Python, JupyterLab, ipywidgets, ipympl, and matplotlib that all match well **and successfully install properly** can be difficult as all those are complex. (`ipympl` is often overlooked. Is that the same on both systems?) Did you restart the browsers and Jupyter all involved on the non-working system? Were the packages installed exactly in the same ways?

Comment: Oh wait, I see matplotlib works. Forget about `ipympl` then. You know the package that is the issue. Plotly is complex too. This gets back to not sure what you are asking about. You know the symptom and the possible cause but then proceed to ask about them here. You should have addressed what you have done to sort out the cause of the issue with Plotly and Voila and not just gone in depth about the symptoms. You already know. And the better one to try as one that should work is [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/master) because I installed Plotly there, too.